# How to insert values in gridview when I click the combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
private void cmbInNa_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt1 = pbl.getinnm(this.cmbInNa.Text.ToString());
        if (dt1 != null) //&& dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbkw = dataGridView1.Columns["cmbkw"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
            cmbkw.DataSource = dt1;
            cmbkw.DisplayMember = "KeyWord";

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbRetu = dataGridView1.Columns["cmbRetu"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;

            cmbRetu.DataSource = dt1;
            cmbRetu.DisplayMember = "col_Return";
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    } 
}
```

How to insert Values in `gridview` when I click the `combobox`, Now I can able to retrive data from database using above code, Like that I want to insert,update values when user selects the `combobox`.

Comment: you want to inssert on click or selected index change

Comment: i want to insert values, As of now now i'm retrieving the data into gridview

Answer (score 0):

Add Row Like this

```
        DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();
        //dg is your Datagridview
        DataGridViewRow dgr = new DataGridViewRow();
        dg.Rows.Add(dgr);
```

Comment: @user3171911 When you need to add a new row ? when user selects an item from combobox ? what do you mean by combobox click ?

Comment: Yes when user select combobox user needs to add rows in gridview, i already made columns in gridview so in those particular column i want to insert values,

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).Rows.Add((dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).NewRow());
```

Comment: Still i'm getting NullReference exception was unhandeled.

Comment: @user3171911 That means you do not have already binded dataSource with datagridView, and which value do you want to add in DGV after comboBox value change? Make more clear your question also.